# check if a node.js file is require.cached

Tags: node.js, caching, require

I'm using the following to reload a node js file:

Edit: I'm using the function below from main.js or any other file to load some other file. In my case I reload file on change using chokidar

```
function requireUncached(modulePath) {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(modulePath)];
  return require(modulePath);
}
```

Let's say I have a file called test.js:

```
requireUncached('./test.js')
```

running the following code:

```
while(true) {
  // Edit: file_loaded is referring to the current file where this code resides
  if (!file_loaded) // file_loaded is the part I need help with
    break;  

  // do something
  // eg:
  console.log('hello')

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}
```

when this file is unloaded (or reloaded with a new version) it will continue running and printing 'hello' indefinitely.

I tried setting a global variable to signal the loop to terminate. But this will interfere with the newly cached file too.

Is there a way a node zone/context can get whether it's cached or not? Or is there a way to completely stop/destroy a running context?

Edit: here's a quick example you can try:

main.js

```
function requireUncached(modulePath) {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(modulePath)];
  return require(modulePath);
}

requireUncached('./test.js')
requireUncached('./test.js')
requireUncached('./test.js')
```

test.js

```
init()

async function init() {
  while (true) {
    console.log('hello')

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
  }
}
```

Run: `node main.js`

Notice how 'Hello' is printed 3 times every second instead of one, because the async function does not stop when using delete require.cache.

Comment: When you say `file_loaded` which file does that refer to?  Itself?  How does `requireUncached` relate to your other snippet?  Can you post an example that is runnable to show what you mean?

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify some things and added a working example